# Icon not displayed for RibbonMenuItem

Tags: wpf, icons, menuitem

I have the following code inside a RibbonSplitButton (which rendered correctly on the 3.5 ribbon CTP verion). I tried to view it using the WPF Ribbon 4.0 library, but it's just not rendering the Icon. Any idea why?

```
<ribbon:RibbonMenuItem Header="Option 3 - icon">
                            <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="Images/wizard-icon16.png"></Image>
                            </ribbon:RibbonMenuItem.Icon>
                        </ribbon:RibbonMenuItem>
```

Comment: It's not related to the image - I've tried placing a textblock instead of the image, but still it's not displaying

Answer (score 7):

Don't use the Icon property, that is inherited from `MenuItem`, and isn't used by the Ribbon control. Use the `ImageSource` property instead.

Comment: This is and should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I also see the same problem. I've try to put even simple text in the Icon property but it just does not show anything. 
I've check the control template and there is just no binding to the Icon property in it. You can use ImageSource to put an image in the menu item icon's place.

I guess it simply bad control template.

Comment: This worked for me. I guess the RibbonMenuItem.Icon property is simply  not connected to anything.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Add a forward slash in front of Images and do a Rebuild Solution.  This is assuming the Images directory is located at the root of your project.</strike>

Is the image's build action set to Content?

HTH

Comment: It's still not working. I've tried placing a textblock instead of the image, but still it's not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image's build action to Resource